# Usar un método hecho en angularjs desde html (una vez que cargue una lista de elementos con ng-repeat)

Tags: javascript, css, html5, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Lo que me pasa es lo siguiente:
Tengo un archivo html, donde con ng-repeat cargo una lista de elementos.
En esta lista, cada elemento tiene el id = "elemento{{a.id}}"

Desde un archivo js (angularjs) cree un método para que me aplique filtros visuales.
El problema es que primero carga el archivo de js, y una vez que todo corrió carga el html. En el método que programe uso esos id, pero.... como todavía el js no termino de correr, el html no cargo y no tengo la lista cargada en cuestión, entonces no tengo los id y me dice que quiero aplicar un estilo a un elemento en null..

Pensaba en crear un evento o algo que use mi método , una vez que la lista en html ya este cargada, pero no se cual usar, quizás angularjs tenga alguno...Alguien sabe alguna solución?

Dejo el código para que se entienda a que me refiero.

**html**

```
<div class="row" id="divZonas" style="margin-left:15px">
    <div class="tab" ng-repeat="a in zonas">
        <button class="tablinks" id="BtnZona" ng-model="ZonaSeleccionada" ng-click="MostrarMesasPorZona(a)">{{a.nombreZona}}</button>

    </div>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="a in mesas" class="col-xs-1" style="margin-right:20px; margin-top:20px;margin-left:25px;">
                            <button type="button" id="{{a.numeroMesa}}" ng-click="AccionMesa(a)" class="btn btn-warning btn-circle btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">

                                {{a.numeroMesa}}
                            </button>
                            <label id="lbl{{a.numeroMesa}}"><i class="fa fa-user-o" id="iconoUser{{a.numeroMesa}}" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
                            <label id="campana{{a.numeroMesa}}"><i class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
                        </div>
```

**AppMesas.js (angularjs)**

```
angular.module("myAppPedidoMozo", []).controller("myCtrlPedidoMozo", function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/api/Mesas/GetMesa/').then(function (response) {
        $scope.mesas = response.data;}); 
$scope.MostrarMesasPorZona = function (Zona) {
    debugger;
    $scope.idZona = Zona.idZona;
    var bandConfirmado = false;
    var Contador = 0;
    var listabanderas = [];
    var listaTempMesas = [];
    //for (var i = 0; i < $scope.mesas[i].length; i++) {
    //  document.getElementById("" + $scope.mesas[i].numeroMesa + "").style.display = 'none';
    //  document.getElementById("lbl" + $scope.mesas[i].numeroMesa + "").style.display = 'none';
    //  document.getElementById("campana" + $scope.mesas[i].numeroMesa + "").style.display = 'none';
    //  document.getElementById("cancelarP" + $scope.mesas[i].numeroMesa + "").style.display = "none";
    //  document.getElementById("billete" + $scope.mesas[i].numeroMesa + "").style.display = "none";
    //}




    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.mesas.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.mesas[i].idZona === Zona.idZona) {
            document.getElementById("" + $scope.mesas[i].numeroMesa + "").style.display = 'inline';
            document.getElementById("lbl" + $scope.mesas[i].numeroMesa + "").style.display = 'inline';
            document.getElementById("campana" + $scope.mesas[i].numeroMesa + "").style.display = 'inline';
        } else {
            document.getElementById("" + $scope.mesas[i].numeroMesa + "").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("lbl" + $scope.mesas[i].numeroMesa + "").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("campana" + $scope.mesas[i].numeroMesa + "").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("cancelarP" + $scope.mesas[i].numeroMesa + "").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("billete" + $scope.mesas[i].numeroMesa + "").style.display = "none";

        }
    }}});
```

Esto es solo una parte pero es para que se vea que quiero usar el método "mostrarMesasPorZona" por defecto, siempre, (no solo cuando haga Click y le pase un parámetro con ng-click ) sino un valor por defecto, por ejemplo Zona 1

Comment: No estoy muy seguro pero, creo que deberias llamar a esa funcion en el método $onInit del ciclo de vida de tu componente. https://toddmotto.com/angular-1-5-lifecycle-hooks#using-oninit

Comment: claro entiendo!!! ahí estuve leyendo... y cual seria mi componente? la mesa no? como hago para llamarla?

Comment: Pues no he trabajo con AngularJs, solo con Angular 2+. Pero entiendo que deberias declararla bajo la declaracion del componente. Antes o despues de la llamada ajax. Y segun la documentacion seria algo como: this.$onInit = funtion(){ this.MostrarMesasPorZona(idZona) }

Answer (score 1):

siguiendo, textualmente, lo que pides en la pregunta, te sugiero que utilices `ng-init`

```
<div ng-repeat="a in mesas" ng-init="$last ? metodoEstilos() : null" ... > 
...  </div>
```

Donde se evalúa que `$last` (variable que solo toma valor cuando es el último item del `ng-repeat`) no sea indefinido o nulo para poder ejecutar el método que requieras: Si tiene valor (significa que es el último) y ejecuta la operación; si no, simplemente retorna un nulo y continúa la ejecución del ciclo.

Comment: Muchas gracias intentare con eso y te cuento :)